# How to update Claim.Principal after login a user with Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-ad-b2c

I currently have a project that user B2C Azure for login. In azure I use 3 customs int fields that contains the result of a selection in some dropdownList. after the login occurs in my HOME Controller, I can read the customfield value in my claimsPrincipal like this:

```
   System.Security.Claims.Claim claim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "extension_RegistrationComplete").SingleOrDefault();
    if (claim != null)
          retour = Convert.ToBoolean(claim.Value);
```

So I can test if all custom fields are completed before continuing. If RegistrationComplete are false, I redirect to a Step2 form page asking the user to choose options in dropdownlist. Then I save it to Azure with the B2C Graph API. But the local ClaimsPrincipal do not have the update so the user stuck in a loop because the local RegistrationConplete is always false.

How can we update the ClaimsPrincipal without re-logging the user? Currently I log the user with

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);
```

Thanks.

Finaly I use this code:

```
var Identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
Identity.RemoveClaim(Identity.FindFirst("AnnounceCount"));
Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AnnounceCount", "Updated Value"));
var authenticationManager = 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new 
AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(Identity), new 
AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what framework you're using, but I've done this in the past by handling `SecurityTokenValidated` in `IAppBuilder.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication`

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = context =>{
                 //some stuff
                 Claim newClaim = new Claim("something", "special");
                 context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(newClaim);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You code help me. But Finalty you can do that from everywhere. Just need to delete the claim and re-add it. I update the question with the code I use.